# How to: Select Distinct objects<T> from multiple Lists<T> with 1 or more properties of same type

Tags: c#, linq

So this is a design question that has vexed me for hours, and I have to reach out to the group for an assist.  I have a collection with thousands of shared entities, and need to retrieve a distinct list of managers from three different properties contained in two lists, two managers in the Stores list, and one manager from warehouse collection.

To simplify the problem, I've written a simple console program that highlights the challenge.  I tossed it together, so yes, I know it's inefficient, but it demonstrates the problem:

```
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DistributionGroup d = new DistributionGroup();
            Console.WriteLine("====Store Managers====");
            foreach(Manager m in d.Stores.Select(m => m.StoreManager).Distinct())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", m.Id, m.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("=====Inv. Managers=====");
            foreach (Manager m in d.Stores.Select(m => m.InventoryManager).Distinct())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", m.Id, m.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("===Warehouse Managers===");
            foreach (Manager m in d.Warehouses.Select(m => m.WarehouseManager).Distinct())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", m.Id, m.Name);
            }                
        }
    }
    public class DistributionGroup
    {
        private Manager m1 = new Manager(1, "Bob Wilson");
        private Manager m2 = new Manager(2, "Chris Warren");
        private Manager m3 = new Manager(3, "Mike Olsen");
        private Manager m4 = new Manager(4, "Aaron Erikson");

        public List<RetailStore> Stores;
        public List<Warehouse> Warehouses;

        public DistributionGroup()
        {
            RetailStore s1 = new RetailStore(1, m1, m1);
            RetailStore s2 = new RetailStore(2, m1, m3);
            RetailStore s3 = new RetailStore(3, m2, m2);
            Warehouse w1 = new Warehouse(1, m4);
            Warehouse w2 = new Warehouse(2, m2);

            Stores = new List<RetailStore>();
            Stores.Add(s1);
            Stores.Add(s2);
            Stores.Add(s3);

            Warehouses = new List<Warehouse>();
            Warehouses.Add(w1);
            Warehouses.Add(w2);
        }
    }

    public class Manager
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public Manager(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id; Name = name;
        }
    }
    public class RetailStore
    {
        public int Id;
        public Manager StoreManager;
        public Manager InventoryManager;
        public RetailStore(int id, Manager mgr, Manager inventoryMgr)
        {
            Id = id;
            StoreManager = mgr;
            InventoryManager = inventoryMgr;
        }
    }

    public class Warehouse
    {
        public int Id;
        public Manager WarehouseManager;
        public Warehouse(int id, Manager mgr)
        {
            Id = id;
            WarehouseManager = mgr;
        }
    }
```

What I need to do is generate a distinct list of Managers from all three properties:

1. RetailStore.StoreManager
2. RetailStore.InventoryManager
3. Warehouse.WarehouseManager

So following the example, the console output would simply be:

> 1:Bob Wilson
>   2:Chris Warren
>   3:Mike Olsen
>   4:Aaron Erikson

I've been trying to figure out the syntax, but LINQ is not a strength, and I'm hoping the group can help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you need to use [Enumerable.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var allManagers = d.Stores.Select(m => m.StoreManager).Union(d.Stores.Select(m => m.InventoryManager))
                                                      .Union(d.Warehouses.Select(m => m.WarehouseManager));
foreach (Manager m in allManagers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", m.Id, m.Name);
}
```

Note that `Union` returns unique values from input sequences so no need to call `Distinct`.

Comment: You're missing the Distinct() but I think you can just tag that at the end.

Comment: @Henk you don't need it, from the msdn "When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded."

Comment: Perfect, thanks, and in looking at the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) I see that union does return the distinct list as desired.

Comment: This will only work if the `Manager` class implements [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151.aspx)

Comment: @MetroSmurf It still works because the same Manager object exists in mutiple lists. But yes, if separate manager objects existed in several lists then Manager would need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (and possibly implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` but overriding is enough to make it work)

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about needing Distinct(). I was thinking about Concat(), which is an alternative solution.